# startActivityForResult requestCode returns -1 for valid int

Tags: android

I am seeing some strange behaviour with the Android startActivityForResult requestCode when opening an activity from a fragment. I have a class that I store request codes so they are in one place and I use those when passing the request code. But I found 41, 51 would return -1 when 21 31 would be fine and it just seems to be those ending in 1 that its happening with. It's baffled me why this would happen, but if anyone has encountered this, please enlighten me to the reasons :)

```
public class RequestCodes {

    // request codes
    public static final int INTRO_ACTIVITY = 1;
    public static final int MAIN_ACTIVITY = 2;
    public static final int ABOUT_ACTIVITY = 3;
    ...
    public static final int EXAMPLE_ACTIVITY = 41;
}
```

Used in fragment

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleActivity.class);
i.putExtra(Extras.ID, id);
startActivityForResult(i, RequestCodes.EXAMPLE_ACTIVITY);
```

the onActivityResult is declared in the fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // used to see the request
    showToast("Request Code = " + requestCode);
}
```

and onBackPressed in the Example activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(Extras.ID, id);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? where is your onactivityonresult declared?

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` does not return request codes. Or -1.

Comment: could you put your onactivityonresult method ?

Comment: also put the code of your ExampleActivity class

Comment: I updated the question with the requested info

Comment: Turns out I'm a moron and found the mistake and there isn't another person on the planet who would make it, so I won't embarrass myself by saying what it is lol